# Creating a JSON object with Python

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have two functions that each create a pandas dataframe. Each function returns the dataframe in the format of a json object. Each function has the below form:

```py
def object1():

    df = pd.DataFrame()

    # some calculations
    # calculations are stored in 'data'
    
    df = df.append(data,True)

    json = df.to_json()

    return json
```

When the the above function is run, the below json object is given:

```py
{"foo1"}
```

To have all of the results in one single json object, I have defined another function that creates a dictionary and stores each of the objects returned from above functions in it. Then the dictionary is turned into a json object using `json.dumps()`. The new function is like below:

```py
def to_json_object():

    item1 = object1
    item2 = object2
    
    json_data = {'object1':item1, 'object2':item2}
    json_data = json_dumps(json_data)

    return json_data
```

The problem is that since the data in functions `object1()` and `object2()` is already turned into a json object once, and then in the `to_json_object()` is again turned into a json, the final result has some back slashes (`\`) that make the final json object actually unusable. The final object looks like below:

```py
{"object1": "{\"foo1\"}, "object2": "{\"foo2\"}}
```

How could I eliminate those nasty back slashes (`\`)?

Comment: I think you want to either return the `dataframe` or a `dict` in `object1()` or convert the json string returned by it back to a dict via `json_loads()` in `to_json_object()`

Comment: @JonSG You mean I first use ```json_loads()``` in ```to_json_object()``` and import the data using that, then create a dictionary and add the data to the dictionary and finally export all of them using ```json_dumps()```? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Maybe this might be the easiest path forward at the moment. Something like `item1 = json.loads(object1())` replacing the first line in `to_json_object()` similarly for the 2nd line. This way `json_data` is a nested dict on like 3 rather than a flatened dict with json strings.

Comment: Why are the functions returning JSON? You should keep everything as Python objects until you're ready to save it to JSON, then convert it.

Comment: @JonSG That sounds cool. Let's see if there's a more efficient way of doing it. Meanwhile, I check your solution.

Comment: @Barmar Because if they don't return json, they need to return a pandas dataframe and dataframes cannot be turned into json using `json.dumps()`.